# CRM Icons for 'Leads, contacts and accounts'

Tags: icons

This is a fairly straightforward question. I'm trying to grab icons for a CRM application. 
These icons are related to people and companies. Now a person could be an existing 'Contact' and a company could be an existing 'Account'. And both a person and a company could be an existing 'Lead' (something/someone) you want to do business with.

I need icons for these 3 things. And I am having trouble settling on any. The current version of my system just has **L, C or A** in a generic triangle warning icon.

Does someone know if there are icons that more intuitively convey these three things?
For existing 'Contact' I feel the 'Person head' icon will work. I'm having trouble finding 'Lead' and 'Account' Icons.

Comment: Flagged as off-topic.  Per the [Faq](http://ux.stackexchange.com/faq): "I'm having trouble coming up with a good icon for feature X. Should I ask here for ideas? - **No**"

Comment: Closed as off topic. Brian is correct; icon request questions are not suited to this site i'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of icons is to convey the intended information as clearly as possible (in this case the fact that a person can be a contact or a lead and a company can be a lead or an account).

So you need four icons:

- Person (contact)
- Person (lead)
- Company (lead)
- Company (account)

My suggestions (though this is only subjective and in the end only you will know if it is right for your application):

- Have 2 icons, a head for 'person' and a building for 'company'.
- For each of these icons have a smaller, inset icon for 'contact, 'lead' and 'account'.  Maybe something like an email, a double arrow or handshake and a folder or dollar sign.

Comment: This is a great suggestion. I will have to be very careful of picking good design as now I am dealing with a slightly complex icon. Its still easy to learn though